# Checking the connection to local server

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, connection, localhost

i want to check the connection from android app to the local server, what is the best way to check the connection every X second to do some work when the server is reachable

for now, I'm using this code

```
public static boolean itsOnline(Context context) {
    String host="google.com"; //put the local server ip instead 
    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        Socket sock = new Socket();
        SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(host,443);

        sock.connect(sockaddr, 2000);
        sock.close();
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Connected to : "+ host, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return true;
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Not Connected to : "+host, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
    }
```

but i want to make it done continually, and if there is a better way i will appreciate any advice.